# Hungarian characters gone when loading from database

Tags: jquery, ajax, character-encoding

I'm extracting database data width jquery to build site content. The problem is: my hungarian characters get lost on the way from the server to the client. For example: "kosárlabda" becomes "Kos�rlabda" etc...

Setting the response headers with php doesn't help (nor ISO-8859-2, nor UTF-8).
I have `<?php header('charset=ISO-8859-2'); ?>` on the top of my called files.

This is the method I use to load the data:

```
function load(type,values) {
    $.get(type+".php", function(data) {
        $("#data").html(data);
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179760](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179760)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

All I needed was:

- putting `mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF-8");` and `mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");` into all php files
- adding an `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to the .htaccess file.