# MYSQL special chars issue

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, character-encoding

I´ve been having this problem for a long time, I´ve searched the internet many times for the solution, tried lots of them but not found an adequate solution.

I really don´t know what to do so if you could please help me I´d be very thankful.
(Sorry for my poor english).

**Question:** How can I solve the charset incompatibility between the input archive and a MYSql table?

**Problem:** When importing the archive from on my computer the information appears in my database, but some chars as `('ã', 'ç', 'á', etc..)` are shown as `?`.

**Aditional information**

1. I'm using MYSql, my version and variable status are:

   ```
   MySQL VERSION : 5.5.10  
   HOST : localhost  
   USER : root  
   PORT : 3306  
   SERVER DEFAULT CHARSET : utf8  
   character_set_client  :  utf8  
   character_set_connection  :  utf8  
   character_set_database  :  utf8  
   character_set_filesystem  :  BINARY  
   character_set_results  :  utf8  
   character_set_server  :  utf8  
   character_set_system  :  utf8  
   collation_connection  :  utf8_general_ci  
   collation_database  :  utf8_general_ci  
   collation_server  :  utf8_general_ci  
   completion_type  :  NO_CHAIN  
   concurrent_insert  :  AUTO
   ```
2. The query that´s being used is:

   ```
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'xxxxx/file.txt' 
   INTO TABLE xxxxTable 
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
   LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' 
   IGNORE 1 LINES
   ( status_ordenar,numero,newstatus,rede,data_emissao,inicio,termino,tempo_indisp
   , cli_afet,qtd_cli_afet,cod_encerr,uf_ofensor,localidades,clientes_afetados 
   , especificacao,equipamentos,area_ofens,descricao_encerr,criticidade,cod_erro
   , observacao,id_falha_perc,id_falha_conf,nba,solucao,falhapercebida,falhaconfirmada
   , resp_i,resp_f,resp_ue,pre_handover,falha_identificada,report_netcool,tipo_falha
   , num_notificacao,equip_afetados,descricao)
   ```
3. About the file being imported: 
   I´ve opened the file with open office whith 3 charsets:

   UTF8 - Gave me strange chars in place of the 'ç', 'ã', etc...
   ISO-8859-1 - OK.
   WIN-1252 - OK.
   ASCII/US - OK.
4. Already tested: I´ve tested some charsets in my database: latin1, utf-8, ascii, but all of them gave me the same result (? instead of 'á', 'ç' etc).
5. Extra: I'm using Java with Java JDBC to generate and send the query.

Comment: How are you viewing the data that you're seeing the '?'?

Comment: I've edited your post but it wasn't clear what the character after `LINES TERMINATED BY` was meant to be. I don't think it makes a difference but if I've got it wrong please change it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file.txt is saved in ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 (these two are very similar), and being interpreted as UTF-8 by MySQL. These are incompatible.

How can I tell?

- See point 3.: the file displays correctly when interpreted as ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252.
- See point 1.: character_set_database  :  utf8

Solution: either convert the file to UTF-8, or tell MySQL to interpret it as ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252.

Background: the characters you provide (ã etc.) are single-byte values in windows-1252, and these bytes are illegal values in UTF-8, thus yielding the '?'s (unicode replacement characters).

Snippet from [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

> LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax
>
> The character set indicated by the character_set_database system variable is used to interpret the information in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, what I did to solve the incompatibility was:
1)Set my database to utf-8.
2)Add "character set LATIN1" to the query to import my file.

I dont know if i´m correct but seem that '2)' forces mysql to read the file as LATIN1.
Well anyway, it solved my problem after many months. 
Case is closed!

Answer (score 0):

Saved your characters with standard Windows Notepad as UTF-8 file (Notepad++ is also OK).

Exact file content:

```
'ã', 'ç', 'á'
```

MySQL version: 5.5.22
Database charset: utf8
Database collation: utf8_general_ci

```
CREATE TABLE `abc` (
  `qwe` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Imported data with command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/test/utf8.txt' 
INTO TABLE abc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
( qwe)
```

Result (displayed in SQLyog):
[image: SQLyog result]

---

So, first - you should check original file with reliable editor (notepad, notepad++). If file corrupted, then you should take another file.

Second - if file is OK, add you Java code for sending data to MySql into question.